# How do you input a javascript variable into php function using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What am I doing wrong here?? Everything works fine and there are no errors in the console but there are also no console logs saying it succeeded

**index file with script:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

       function upVote(picNum)
          {

              var pictureNumber = parseInt($("#" + picNum).attr("id"));


              $.ajax({
                 url: "upload/pics/changeVote.php",
                 data: {"picNum":pictureNumber},
                 type:'post',
                 dataType:'json',
                 success: function(output_string){
                    PictureNumber = output_string['picturenumber'];
                    alert(PictureNumber);
                }
              });
              var currentVote = parseInt($("#" + picNum).attr("value"));  
              alert("pictureNumber is " + pictureNumber + "and currentVote is " + currentVote); //here to help me, no functionality

              $newVote = currentVote + 1;

              alert($newVote); //here to help me
          }
   </script>
```

**/upload/pics/changeVote.php**

```
<?php

   $picNum = $_POST['picNum'];
function otherFileFunc($pic){
  $final = $pic + 1;
  return $final;
}
$outputnumber = function($picNum);
$array = ('picturenumber' => $outputnumber);
echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Mistake in **/upload/pics/changeVote.php**

```
$outputnumber = function($picNum);
```

has to be:

```
$outputnumber = otherFileFunc($picNum);
```

you can't use `function()`, you should use the function name instead.